# Passing touches from subview of UIButton back to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Suppose I have a `UIView` named **Cake**. **Cake** has a gesture recognizer.

Now, suppose I have a `UIButton` named **Bob**.

I add **Cake** as a subview to **Bob**:

```
[Bob addSubview: Cake];
```

Now, **Bob**, the `UIButton`, no longer responds the control event touch up inside.

I want **Cake** to be able to handle the touch while **Bob** simultaneously handles the touch as well. Currently, **Cake** can handle the touch, but **Bob** lazily does nothing.

Things I have tried:

- Setting `cancelsTouchesInView` of **Cake**'s gesture recognizer to `NO`
- Implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerdelegate` for **Cake**'s gesture recognizer and always returning `YES` for the `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` method
- Subclassing `UIGestureRecognizer` and calling `[self.view.nextResponder touchesSomething:touches withEvent:event];` in each of the `touchesSomething` (`touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, etc.) methods (I've also confirmed that the next responder IS IN FACT the `UIButton` that is supposed to handle the control events)
- Not using a gesture recognizer and instead just using the `touchesSomething` methods in the `UIView` (**Cake**) + passing through the `touchesSomething` calls to all of `super`, `self.superview`, `self.nextResponder` and more.

Does anyone know a good way to make this work?

Comment: You want to call a method, when cake is pressed and if bob is pressed additionally another method?

Comment: I want to add a subview to a UIButton that has a gesture recognizer and doesn't interfere with the UIButton's regular functionality.

Comment: Ah ok! The button uses an action?

Comment: Yes, the button is supposed to respond with an action for control event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is the following:

Make sure, that you set the UserInteraction of the subview to false! Now the action of the button should be called correctly.

Now add the event parameter to the action:

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Inside the action check if the press was inside the subview

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    // get location
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    // check position
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.subview.frame, location) {
        // call selector like the gesture recognizer here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need my subview to be able to be placed into an arbitrary UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm trying to make, Cake, is a view that can be placed as a subview into any button without additional setup - its a decorative view of sorts. The gesture recognizer of Cake is there to make a small animation

Then you're going about this all wrong. Take away the gesture recognizer of Cake; you don't need it. You're trying to get Cake to respond to *Bob* being pressed. But that's easy; Bob's a button! The button *already* tells you everything that's happening — it's being highlighted etc. So all you need is a UIButton subclass that tells Cake when to do its animation.

Comment: The thing is that the "**Cake**" I'm making is something that I want to be able to put as a subview into an arbitrary UIView, not just a UIButton. The button is the case that's holding me up.

Comment: If you don't ask the question to which you really want to know the answer, how can I help intelligently? You keep revealing additional pieces of the spec like cards in a poker hand. Just tell me what you're really trying to do!

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I was saying enough. I did ask the question that I want the answer to, but I want a direct answer and not a workaround, which I guess I should have specified. I'm building a UIView subclass that I want to be able to put as a subview in any view. The purpose of this subview is to show an animation based on where a user touched the view. This should work for buttons or other views for which user interaction is enabled (e.g. selectable cells). The point is to give the user feedback when they touch something that is tappable.

Comment: In my view, you asked a question full of highly specific assumptions about the best way to do something, instead of asking how to do that thing.

Comment: I thought that my question was pretty clear in this regard, but I'll try to be even clearer in the future.

Comment: Really? Your question was all about mediating touches between two views. But that if that's completely the wrong approach?

Comment: I said that I have a view thats a subview of a button and that I want both the button to respond to control events and the subview to respond to the gesture recognizer. I reread the question and it seems clear to me. I didn't say, for instance, that the gesture recognizer is optional. I'm sorry that you feel that I wasn't clear enough, but let's not waste time with semantics. If you have a solution, I would love to read that instead.

Comment: "and that I want both the button to respond to control events and the subview to respond to the gesture recognizer" Right. And I'm saying don't assume that. The button is already responding; you don't need additional touch detection here.

Comment: This is where I'll agree that more context would have helped. As I said before, this subview should work both in a UIButton and just another UIView. The easy answer is to have two different ways to deal with UIButtons and UIViews, but I'm trying to make a library that is more generalizable if possible so that I can just drop the subview into anything.